# Using Glimpse with Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data;

Tags: c#, .net, glimpse

I am trying to add [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/) to my web application.  It is working but I am missing one of the best features - i.e. the ability to see how many SQL queries run on each page.

My application is using rather old school Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data;  to create a database instance and then run a stored proc to return data.

I found a Glimpse EnterpriseLibrary.Data nuget package [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Glimpse.EnterpriseLibrary.Data/) which I thought might work but it is not what I need

Looking at the Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data; dll in my DAL layer it is Version 5.0.414.0 and Runtime Version v2.0.50727.  The Enterprise library nuget package above has a dependency on a higher version of the Enterprise library.data and I dont want to upgrade this in case it breaks something.

This is how my current DB layer code looks:

```
// Some method to get data
Database db = MyDatabaseFactory.MyDB;

var sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(StoredProcedures.MyStoredProc);
sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

using (IDataReader dr = db.ExecuteReader(sqlCmd))
{
//Impl removed for brevity
```

My DB Factory then looks like:

```
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data;

namespace MyProj.DAL
{
    class MyDatabaseFactory
    {
        internal static Database MyDB
        {
            get
            {                
                return DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("MyDB");               
            }
        }
```

Is there anyway I can use reflection so that Glimpse will be able to inspect the SQL running?

Was thinking I could possibly use something similar to the code that the Nuget package above uses which is - just not sure what changes to make so thet GlimpseSqlDatabase inherits from Database rather than SqlDatabase:

```
public class GlimpseSqlDatabase : SqlDatabase
{
    private static readonly FieldInfo dbProviderFactoryField =
        typeof(Database).GetField("dbProviderFactory", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    public GlimpseSqlDatabase(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    {
        dbProviderFactoryField.SetValue(this, DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.SqlClient"));
    }
}
```